# Best practices to read 5000 line apex codes?

Tags: apex

I have been assign a existing apex class, it has more than five thousand lines. I am bit confused how can I read entire code so that I can get detailed info about the class functionality. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your question is a bit broad for our forum, but I'll throw out some pointers from my experience.

The number one thing to remember is not to get hung up on the details. Stylistic quirks can be hard to let go, but paying any attention to them in such a huge mess is going to do you no favors. One concession to this rule that I usually make is to spend a little time normalizing the indentation, so the structure of the code is easier to visually interpret.

One thing you *should* do to help you grok what is going on is to build an [abstract syntax tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree). Understanding the structure of the code is what you need to get down first. You can do it in your head or on paper without much more knowledge than that, and I know [Robert Sösemann](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/256/robert-s%C3%B6semann) is working on a [plugin for Eclipse](https://github.com/Up2Go/codeclimate-apex) that you can use if that is your IDE of choice. I haven't got Eclipse running on my machine yet, so I can't provide you with specific installation instructions, unfortunately. Related: [#CodeMetricsForApex](https://twitter.com/hashtag/CodeMetricsForApex) and [@CodeClimate](https://twitter.com/codeclimate)

Comment: The Force.com IDE's Outline view is working(ish), which has helped me more than once.

Comment: Does it also build an AST for you? It seems there are a couple different options for how to do it. I certainly don't have much experience with which one is best. I usually use paper; it helps me think. But with 5000 lines, I doubt that would be very effective.

Comment: Nah, but you get a list of members, functions, etc. It's better than nothing. Usually once a function gets more than about 100 lines, I usually take the time to refactor. I really like the AST tool you linked though.

Comment: OP's issue brings to mind the [Prepare Three Envelopes](http://www.design.caltech.edu/erik/Misc/Prepare_3_Envelopes.html) strategy

Comment: @sfdcfox I do believe he's looking for contributors.

Comment: @AdrianLarson I'll see if I have time. I've been wanting to spice up the Force.com CLI for a while now, and it'd be an awesome addition.